# Losing my mind trying to fetch the JSON from bitcoin charts

Tags: live-data

I have tried various attempts at calling the JSON from bitcoin charts using Javascripts, including using AJAX get method and also the getJson method, but neither are working for me. I saw ways on how to do it using Ruby, but I have no experience using that, so can anyone guide me to how or where I can get it done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "neither are working for me", what do you mean? Are you getting an error message, syntax errors, or what?